# Помогите разобраться с хэндлерами

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Добрый день начал изучать процесс написание ботов на питоне. Уроки по которым учился используют aiogram. И вот в этих уроках все функции регистрируются через dp.message.register(func, условие вызова), но везде где я в остальных местах смотрю примеры если чего то не понимаю пишется @dp.message_hendler. Я пробовал так писать, но у меня всё после dp. зачеркивает и я принципе не понимаю разницы. Можно краткий ликбез?

вот так не работает кнопка меню

```
@dp.message(text=['Стажировка бармена'])
async def bar_stajirovka(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Стажировка бармена', reply_markup=kb.main_bar)
```

а вот так работает

```
async def bar_stajirovka(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('Стажировка бармена', reply_markup=kb.main_bar)

dp.message.register(bar_stajirovka, text=['Стажировка бармена'])
```

что не так?

сделал по примеру с какого то учебника - пишет хэндлер не зарегистрирован

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
import logging

TOKEN = "1111111"
ADMIN_ID = 111111

bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(commands=['start'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nНапиши мне что-нибудь!")


@dp.message(commands=['help'])
async def process_help_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Напиши мне что-нибудь, и я отпрпавлю этот текст тебе в ответ!")


@dp.message()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, msg.text)

async def starter():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO
    )
    bots = Bot(TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    print('Starter')
    await dp.start_polling(bots)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(starter())
```

Comment: Он не работает потому что бот его не увидел, вы бы показали его расположение

Comment: @oleksandrigo Как и есть ли в этом какое то преимущество или чисто вопрос привычки и личного комфорта?

Comment: если вы извращенец то вы используете второй вариант, если нет - первый. Никаких преимуществ во-втором варианте нет. Вам достаточно импортировать модуль со всеми вашими хендлерами, которые сделали через декоратор. Всё

Comment: @oleksandrigo почему то примерно так и думал и даже несколько раз пытался переписать под первый, но не получается. Не понимаю что значит импортировать модуль? Как это сделать?

Comment: ну сделай пакет (папка с файлом инит) куда кидай файлы в которых лежат нормальные хендлеры. Ну и записывай эти файлы в инит. И этот пакет импортируй при запуске бота Пример https://imgur.com/a/AWPiltJ

Answer (score 0):

Вот нормальный бот

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("text")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Есть ощущение что на aiogram 3  это как то по другому запускать всё надо потому что у мня вот https://imgur.com/a/je7Tud7 Всё что поменял токен напрямую вписал

Comment: А зачем вам 3 версия? она же сырая

Comment: Не знаю, я вообще не сразу понял что у меня третья... Начал изучать, всё делал по уроку и в какой то момент понял, что все примеры, которые есть в интернете мне почему то не подходят... Начал выяснять и вот, а сейчас уже обидно менять, очень много всего написал